# Can we configure PCie Max Payload Size (MPS) device capabilities and device control registers?

Tags: linux-kernel, intel, xilinx, hpc, pci-e

I have a PCIe endpoint(Xilinx DMA) device with 1024 MPS which is connected to Intel CPU via PCIe switch.
In Linux system, lspci shows 1024 MPS in DevCap register for this endpoint but it's enumerated with only 128 MPS in DevCTl.

Many other devices also connected with same PCie bridge port with different MPS capabilities.

From the same tree some devices having only 128 max MPS capabilities (like VT-d, APIC etc)  and few devices like XDMA having 1024 bytes MPS support.

So all devices gets enumerated with minimum MPS size which is 128.
I have attached a screenshot to show the tree and MPS size.

Two questions

1. Can we increase MPS size in device capabilities (DevCap) registers? (most unlikely but just want to confirm)
2. Can we increase MPS size in device control (DevCtl) registers for [f3:00.0] Xilinx DMA controller or [f4:00.0] NVIDIA GPU given in screenshot.

[image]

Thanks & Regards,
Hardik

Comment: AFAIK, the max payload size is negotiated between the device and the processor, while most intel processors' max payload size is 128 according to their datasheets, and any attempt to increase this value by writing the specific register will fail. I am now meeting the same issue, any relevant material is welcome.